# Why classification algorithms have very high error?

Tags: classification, svm

Let me explain more about my question:  I have collected 2000 data as the following:

### age           sex         education         residence     music

young         male        Primary_school     east            mixture
middle-agee   female      Primary_school     north           mixture
young         female      Bachelor           south_east      mixture
young         male        Master_degree      east            mixture
old           male        physician          east            traditional
middle-agee   female      Bachelor           east            mixture
young         female      Bachelor           center          mixture
teeneger      female      Primary_school     west            mixture
young         female      Master_degree      east            mixture
young         female      Master_degree      south_east      mixture
young         female      Primary_school     south           mixture
middle-agee   female      illiterate         east            mixture
middle-agee    male        Bachelor          south           traditional
young         female      Master_degree      east            mixture
old           male        Primary_school     south_east      traditional
middle-agee   female     Bachelor            east            traditional
young         female      Master_degree       south          mixture
....

In our city, we have 22 districts with total population 12000,000 people. I have collected 2000 samples as the above from different locations by asking question from people each of the above question, like  what is your age?, your education? your sex ?  your district ( north, east, west,...) and what is your favorite music ( which kind of music do you like to listen)?

Now I want to use classification algorithm to predict if a new person selected from one area with specific age; sex; education; her residence (area), then we want to predict which kind of music she like to listen to?

I use R and examine 5 top algorithms such as svm, lda; knn; randon Forest and figured that the error is more than %70.
[The OOB estimate of  error rate is so high ~~%70]

Could you please explain why this bias and error happened?

Best regards
Amir

Comment: There's no way for us to answer this, as you did not supply details on how you generated your data.  For example, if you generated your predictors and classes independently, then you would expect any model to achieve at best an accuracy of 10%, so by that measure you are doing well.  There is no absolute measure of a "good" error rate, it depends on the quality and quantity of the data you have.

Comment: Have you considered that there is some real noise in the data & that level of error is appropriate?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's simple: because the information to make more accurate predictions is just **not contained** in the data. You cannot make more accurate inference, most probably.

I give you an example: I like to play guitar, study and have my own laptop. In which country do I live?

No chance to get that right...